# Positioning a 3d object in the corners of the canvas - three.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have a 3d object that I want to be able to automatically position in either corner of my canvas regardless of the canvas's size.
[image: default position of object in canvas]

I came across this stackoverflow solution:
[image: change the initial position of my geometry]

and applied the following code to my object:

```
mesh.position.set(-(window.innerWidth), (window.innerHeight), 0)
```

which results in this:

[image: Object in the top left-hand corner of canvas]

As you can see it is only part of the object and I would like to have it positioned in full view, like this, but it would need to look consistent on different canvas sizes (maybe for mobile use):

[image: object correctly positioned in corner]

I have also attached an example of my setup

[image: 3d position]

I just need some pointers on how I can achieve this, so any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `THREE.Raycaster()` with `THREE.Plane()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.set(0, 5, 10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "green"
}));
scene.add(box);

var plane = new THREE.Plane().setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1));

btnMove.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var corner = new THREE.Vector2();
var cornerPoint = new THREE.Vector3();

function onClick() {
  corner.set(-1, -1); // NDC of the bottom-left corner
  raycaster.setFromCamera(corner, camera);
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, cornerPoint);
  box.position.copy(cornerPoint)
    .add(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, -1)); // align the position of the box
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#btnMove {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnMove">Move bottom-left</button>
```

Comment: Hi @prisoner849, thank you for the example. I have applied your code to my own example [3d position + plane](https://jsfiddle.net/w9914420/p8L7fbsw/55/) and whilst it does work, you can see that the object is not exactly lined up on the plane like yours. I wonder if you could explain the maths behind getting it to work correctly in any situation, what numbers do I need to change to get this to work in my example.

Comment: @MrPhilly Your box has dimensions of 200x200x200, thus, the coplanar point of the plane will be [0, 0, 100] (z is the coordinate of the front side of the cube), and then the aligning additional vector will be [100, 100, -100] (it means that you set front-left-bottom point of the cube to the point of intersection between the ray and the plane)

Comment: so I have translated what you said to this: I changed the plane value to this `var plane = new THREE.Plane().setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100));` and then changed the value of mesh.postion.copy within the `onClick` function to `mesh.position.copy(cornerPoint).add(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, -100)); ` and this seems to work [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/w9914420/p8L7fbsw/68/)

Comment: `.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100))` should look like `.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 100))` as the first parameter is a normal and its length must be equal to 1. If the answer solved your question, mark it as accepted.